# Pooling data with unequal sample sizes

Tags: regression, logistic, sample-size, pooling, tobit-regression

I have searched far and wide for a clear answer to my question (and am aware that a clear answer may not exist) and I'm hoping someone might be able to help me.

I have survey data for 4 samples of unequal sizes ($n=500$, $490$, $101$, $103$). I want to pool the data for regression (logit and tobit specifically) analysis, but am not clear how to account for the different sample sizes and their effects on the model outcomes. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Why would you not just combine it all into one sample with size = 500 + 490 + 101 + 103?

Comment: Maybe we're talking about some form of clustered or stratified sampling?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to clarify - they are samples for a 2x2 experimental design. The surveys are otherwsie equivalent. I am testing for the influence of these treatments on outcomes - and I worry that in this case, unequal sample size may be a problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to determine if this is useful to do. Consider for example two scenarios given your data:

- The groups are incredibly similar, the measures are exactly the same, and the groups were measured at the same time points.
- The groups have systematic differences, the measures for each group are created by the site-administrators, and the group data is collected at different years.

Now you have at least mentioned that the surveys are equivalent. But I am primarily worried about the group equivalence issue. One can combine the samples as suggested by Peter, but we need to know if there are substantial issues in doing so. For example, if we have one group that is 2 standard deviations below the other group in the dependent variable, will it be reasonable to include that as one group in the model we are using? This could be potentially problematic, especially if we care about the differences between groups from a theory standpoint (such as men vs. women).

In any case, they can be *potentially* combined, but it is advisable to do some exploratory data analysis beforehand.